# html5 canvas partitioning jquery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

i am learning html5 canvas, i tried drawing a canvas and filled it with some color with below code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

**html**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

but now i want to get a part of this canvas like right now its 100x100, i want a part of 50x50 from 0,0 position of it, any ideas ? how can i do it?, I have searched alot but not found any example like that !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The canvas context object has a getImageData(xleft,ytop,xright,ybottom) If you want the image data from 0,0 to 50,50 ...

```
imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,50,50);
```

Imagedata also has a data property where you can change the canvas pixel by pixel

```
imageData.data;
```

After changing the image data you can use putImageData to place it back onto the canvas

```
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0,0);
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 75,75); /* or place it starting a pixel 75 left 75 top */
```